# How to acquire DualEELS spectra by DM script?

Tags: hardware, dm-script

I would like to acquire both low-loss and high-loss EELS spectra simultaneously in DualEELS mode by DM script. However, the command for acquiring an EELS spectrum `EELSAcquireSpectrum()` can obtain only single EELS spectrum.

Is there an appropriate scripting commands for DualEELS acquisition?

My system is *GMS2.x*, but please tell me even if such a command is available in only *GMS3.x*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GMS 3.2** (Possible also for GMS 2.3)

---

I am not aware of any specific command for DualEELS. As a rought workaround: When you start the acquistions via `EELSInvokeCaptureButton()` or `EELSInvokeViewButton()` the mode you have set on your UI will be followed. You then need to grab the two front-most images per script.

This is a rough example script:

```
EELSInvokeCaptureButton()
image low,high
while ( EELSAcquisitionIsActive() )
{
    Result(" \n waiting..." )
    sleep( 0.1 )
}

high := GetImageDocument( 0 ).ImageDocumentGetImage( 0 )
low := GetImageDocument( 1 ).ImageDocumentGetImage( 0 )

low.ImageSetName( low.ImageGetName() + " - l" )
high.ImageSetName( high.ImageGetName() + " - h" )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. It is a nice idea, but "EELSInvokeButton()" and "EELSInvokeViewButton()" do not work on my GMS2.3 system. Previously, I have heard that these commands are new one supported from GMS3.x from a service engineer of Gatan. On your GMS2.3 system, do these work correctly?

Comment: @kachigusa I couldn't check if they work properly, but I think they at least *exist* in the latest GMS 2.3(.2) version. You may also try `EELSStartAcquisition()` in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt advice. I have tried "EELSStartAcquisition()", and I confirmed it works correctly on my GMS 2.30.542.0 system. However, "EELSInvokeButton()" and "EELSInvokeViewButton()" still do not work on my system. Is my system older than the version you mentioned?

Comment: @kachigusa "Does not work" or "Does not exist" ? (If you try, check the error in the results-window.)  But yes, the latest published version is GMS 2.3.2 according to Gatan's ftp-site where you can [download the latest](ftp://ftp.gatan.com/pub/software/PC/) version.

Comment: "EELSInvokeButton()" and "EELSInvokeViewButton()" do not exist on my system. So, should I install latest version of GMS2.3.2?

Comment: @kachigusa I don't know the policies at your end regarding changing software on microscope computers (online systems), but generally an upgrade to a later version within a "major" version is a good thing regarding bug-fixes etc. So I would say, yes GMS 2.3.2 might be better for you than GMS 2.3.0, but I don't want to take any responsibilyt here :c)

Comment: @kachigusa But if you get your script to work with the EELSStartAcquisition(), there is no need to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful advices. Firstly, I'm going to write a script using "EELSStartAcquisition()".